# Why are the random_effects filled with NA's?

Tags: r, random-forest, mixed-models

I am using the MERF function from the LongituRF package and trying to apply it my dataset. The results for the random_effects are NA more often than not and I don't understand why.

> library(LongituRF)
> data <- read.csv('../../RF/0_rf_input/subsample_1_all/train_MRF_table_predictors_sat_meteo_static.csv')
>
> dateInts <- tibble(dateInt = 1:length(unique(data$datetime)),
> datetime = sort(unique(data$datetime)))
>
> data <- data %>% arrange(id, datetime) %>% inner_join(dateInts, by = 'datetime')
>
> ids <- sample(data$id, 3) # select only three id's for testing
> data5 <- data %>% filter(id %in% ids)  %>% select(-datetime)
> data5 <- data5[1:10, 27:34]
> smerf <- LongituRF::MERF(X = as.matrix(data5[, 28:31]), Y = as.vector(data5$obs),
> id=data5$id, Z = as.matrix(data5[, 32]),
> mtry = 1,
> ntree = 10,
> iter = 1,
> time = data5$dateInt,
> sto = 'none'
> )
>
> smerf$random_effects # are the predicted random effects for each individual.

Depending on which id's are selected the code will return NA's for the random_effects

[selected few lines from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aufWI.png)